# How to remove the handles from this joint bathroom faucet

Tags: faucet, bathroom-fixtures

There doesn't seem to be a way to unscrew the handles from this faucet. Anyone have any tips?

[image]

Comment: Try turning the chrome sleeves below the handles.

Answer (score 1):

Tough to tell exactly from the pic but it appears the only way to access the cartridge/washers inside would be to close both water supply lines, and carefully unscrew the flange (round top piece) that mounts to the valve body with a pair of pliers using caution not to scratch the chrome finish. Once that flange in removed the entire faucet handle and guts should screw out.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.